# Rendering glitch in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

I've created a menu that moves to the current window position by scrolling. When I scroll up and down right after, sometimes a glitch appears on Chrome 30 with OS X 10.9 and Windows 7. After hovering, the anchor tag jumps to the right position (1 pixel up). Is there anything wrong with my code? Is this a known bug?

**Check this [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Hb3jS/)!**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var newTop = ($(window).scrollTop() + 40) +'px';
    $('#menu').stop().animate({ top: newTop}, 500);
  });
});
```

[image: glitch]

**Edit:** It's fixed in Chrome 31.

Comment: It doesn't look like the jQuery `.animate()` is causing it, because the same thing appears with css transitions: http://jsfiddle.net/Hb3jS/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm fairly certain this is a rendering bug since:

1. Manually triggering a repaint causes the glitch to go away.
2. The glitch doesn't occur in other browsers I tested.

Fortunately, triggering a repaint is a fairly straight-forward workaround, albeit an annoying one:

I added a callback to the animation:

```
$('#menu').stop().animate({ top: newTop }, 500, function(){
  $('#menu').css('overflow', 'hidden');
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#menu').css('overflow', 'auto');
  }, 10);
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Hb3jS/4/)

Unfortunately, it seems both the setting and unsetting of some property (here I chose `overflow`) was necessary. The `10` is a little sketchy, but when you're working around a browser rendering bug, I'm not sure you can do much better.

Best of luck!

Comment: I like this solution. Maybe it's not as elegant as xec's, but it works in old browsers, too. Thanks a lot. I will use your code.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Adam, this is definitely a rendering bug. If you animate the menu using the [`translate()` transform-function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function#translate%28%29) instead, it does not happen.

There are other bonuses to using this method as well: http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/

jQuery core does not allow you to animate using `translate()` out of the box, but there is a plugin that enables this at http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/ , or you can opt for using `.css()` and let [css transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions) do the heavy lifting.

---

Here is an **example using the plugin**:

```js
var menu = $("#menu");
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var newTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    menu.stop().transit({ y: newTop +'px' }, 500);
});
```

Plugin demo at http://jsfiddle.net/Hb3jS/5/

---

Here is an example using **CSS transitions**:

#### js

```js
var menu = $("#menu");
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var newTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    menu.css({ transform: 'translateY(' + newTop +'px)' });
});
```

#### css

```css
#menu { 
    transition: all .5s;
}
```

CSS demo at http://jsfiddle.net/Hb3jS/6/

Comment: Very elegant solution. Do you have an idea why it directly jumps to the destination when I scroll twice (Windows)?

Comment: @Tobias No, but it might be some bug in the transit plugin. Seems fine with plain CSS transitions. http://jsfiddle.net/Hb3jS/6/

Comment: Oh, I see. It seems to be incompatible with jQuerys stop(). Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Tobias That could be it. In any case, i removed the word "nice" from my description of the plugin ;) If you depend on backwards compatibility I'd probably go for Adam's workaround too.

Comment: Haha, you really deleted the "nice". Thanks for updating your solution. I like the way without the plugin.